# learning how to create width size method

Tags: javascript, function

I am creating a function that holds two variables.
The ID variable which gets the element ( box ) and the second variable is call width which holds a width value for the id ( box ).

I keep getting this error  " width is not defined".

Can someone out there please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
<button type="button" onClick="width('box','1000')" >click me </button>

#box{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}



function widthSize( width, id )
{
  id = '';
  width = ''+px;
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the values of the parameter that you pass from your html `onclick=()` to your javascript function. Once it is in a variable that way you can use it in manipulating the styles of your element.

Because you have inputed the passed parameter straight to the `document.getElementById()` you get the error of `Uncaught Reference error: xxx is not defined`.

Below is a sample.

```css
#box{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('box','1000')">Try it</button>

<p id="box"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(id,width) {
 var string = id;
  var size = width+'px';
    
  document.getElementById(string).style.width = size;
}
</script>
```